# How to check if a string has image in java

Tags: java, string, image

I have a clob field (database) explanation read as rich text string from input json. How can I check whether this rich text has images or not in java.

Comment: Can you supplement us with the string that has the image

Comment: What does it mean for a string to "have images"?

Comment: Can you elaborate on a String having Images ?

Comment: Updated the question. Basically requirement is to read images from rich text string.

Comment: You would reverse whatever process converted the image into a rich text string.